# Tracking deliverables for different donation levels

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

I'm working on tracking deliverables for a non-profit. When a donation is made at a particular level, specific benefits are included. For example, a donation of $100 is Level 1, which includes A, B and C as deliverables. A $250 Donation is Level 2, which includes A, B, C, D, and E as deliverables. And so on...

Deliverables need to tracked as they are not always provided at the same time as the donation is made. A and B might be provided right away, but C might not be for a few months later. Some are virtual benefits, others are physical that need to be mailed (event tickets, etc).

My initial thought is to create Products for A,B,C,D,E, etc and create specific Pricebooks for each donation level. When a donation record is created, an APEX trigger would select the correct Pricebook and add all the Products in the Pricebook as deliverables.

I'm at a loss as to what object I should be tracking these deliverables. Is there a standard object I should be using, or should I be creating a custom object. Or is this the wrong approach? Can you suggest something better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a custom object over Products, let me explain. Products represent an entitlement of committed revenue (Opportunity), and as such are bound directly to that revenue. Opportunity Line Items, once added to the opportunity, control the opportunity amount and I don't think you want that in this case. You really want the donation amount separate from the deliverables.

I think you are better off with a top-level object for deliverables, with a junction object to connect them to opportunities as needed.

Comment: If I understand your proposed solution, I would have three objects as follows: Donations (Contact, Level, $ Amount), Deliverables - Junction Object (Lookup to Donations, Lookup to Benefit, Delivered?, Delivery Date), and Benefits (Name, Level). I would still use an APEX trigger that on creation of a Donation, looks up all the benefits of that level, and then creates a deliverable entry for each benefit. Correct?

Comment: As long as Donations is the standard Opportunity object, then yes.

Comment: I have part of the NPSP installed to get the Individual accounts model. I had started creating a custom object for the Donations (tied to a Contact or Account), not using the Opportunity object. I see there is now version 3.0 of the NPSP out. I guess I'll need to fire up a sandbox and do more exploration of the standard objects and also dig more into the Donations component of the NPSP. But at least I now know how to implement the deliverables!

Comment: I do not recommend a custom object for Donations when Opportunity perfectly fits for that use case.